# Docker cannot find file listed in .gitignore

Tags: git, docker, dockerfile, gitignore, dockerignore

I got an issue where Docker could not find files listed in .gitignore.

For example, my directory structure looks like this:

```
- project_folder
  - WebServer.py
  - DockerFile 
  - config
    - privateKey.json
```

I added `config/` to `.gitignore` file to protect the private key, but I got `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: config/privateKey.json` error when deploying my project with `gcloud run deploy`. The error went away if I deleted `config/` from .gitignore.

Is there a way to solve this issue and keep `config/` in `.gitignore`?

Thanks!

Here is my DockerFile:

```
# Use the official lightweight Python image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/python
FROM python:3.10-slim

# Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the Knative logs
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./
# Install production dependencies.
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Run the web service on container startup. Here we use the gunicorn
# webserver, with one worker process and 8 threads.
# For environments with multiple CPU cores, increase the number of workers
# to be equal to the cores available.
# Timeout is set to 0 to disable the timeouts of the workers to allow Cloud Run to handle instance scaling.
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 "WebServer:create_app()"
```

My dockerignore

```
Dockerfile
README.md
*.pyc
*.pyo
*.pyd
__pycache__
.pytest_cache
weight_upload_workflow.py
.git
.gitignore
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Include the commands you are running, and the files needed for someone else to reproduce the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when deploying my project with `gcloud run deploy`.

The [gcloud topic `gcloudignore`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore) documentation includes:

> The default content of the generated `.gcloudignore` file, which can be overriden with `--ignore-file`, is as follows:
>
> ```
> .gcloudignore
> .git
> .gitignore
> ```

So it is possible that adding `config/` to `.gitignore` would end up  preventing its upload due to the generated `.gcloudignore`

[BMitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596285/bmitch) points out in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980443/docker-cannot-find-file-listed-in-gitignore/75980533?noredirect=1#comment134009049_75980533) to [`gloud run deploy --source`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy#--source):

> If `--ignore-file` is not specified, use `.gcloudignore` file.
> If a `.gcloudignore` file is absent and a `.gitignore` file is present in the local source directory, `gcloud` will use a generated Git-compatible `.gcloudignore` file that respects your `.gitignored` files.

Comment: Hi VonC! I did not have ```config/``` in Dockerignore. ```config/``` was in ```.gitignore```

Comment: @FYY In that case, it should have been copied in the resulting Docker image.

Comment: You beat me to it, gcloud docs are at: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy, see the details on `--source`.

Comment: @FYY I have updated the answer to address your edit

Comment: Thanks, @BMitch and @VonC! I solved the issue by adding a .gcloudignore file. Thanks, my friends!